# Force moving a Pod from one worker Node to another

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'd need to force moving a Pod from one Openshift Node to another, in order to do some performance tests. From the documentation it seems that setting the nodeSelector in the Deployment config is the way to go, but it doesn't work, according to my tests.
Here is what I have tried as a test:

**Create nginx Pod**

```
oc new-app -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sclorg/nginx-ex/master/openshift/templates/nginx.json
```

The Pod is running on "ip-10-0-121-229.us-east-2.compute.internal" Node.
Now I patch the node selector, setting a target Node:

```
oc patch dc nginx-example  -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"nodeSelector":{"kubernetes.io/hostname": "ip-10-0-169-74.us-east-2.compute.internal"}}}}}'
```

However the Pod is still running on the same Node. Even by killing the Pod it re-attaches there.
Any suggestion?
Thanjs

Comment: Hi, can you run `oc get events `? what type of events are happening

Comment: doesn't make sense. When you patch the DepoloymetnConfig (I guess dc is that right?), and then do `kubectl get dc -oyaml` can you see the `nodeSelector` parameter added to the template? And when you do the same with the pod, does it appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nodeName` field in your pod spec to schedule the pod yourself, rather than scheduler do it.

`oc explain pod.spec.nodeName`

```
FIELD:    nodeName <string>

DESCRIPTION:
     NodeName is a request to schedule this pod onto a specific node. If it is
     non-empty, the scheduler simply schedules this pod onto that node, assuming
     that it fits resource requirements.
```

you can patch it in similar way. Don't forget to delete nodeSelctor fields

`oc patch dc nginx-example  -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"nodeName": "ip-10-0-169-74.us-east-2.compute.internal"}}}}'`

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 13):

you can try this -

```
kubectl get pod -o  wide
```

this will give you the VM on which your pod is running

then execute

```
kubectl cordon {name_of_that_node_in_which_POD_is_running}
```

then delete the pods, those you want to get aligned to other node

then run

```
kubectl uncordon {the_node_that_was_cordoned_above}
```

Comment: If you use this command you will lose your pod for a while, until you re-deploy it on another node.