# Is there any way I can temporarily suspend routing requests to my pod?

Tags: kubernetes

My service listens to another gRPC server that streams data. The user can send a request to start their own subscriptions or to stop them.

There will be a time when garbage collection kicks in making the user threads in pod to be suspended.

Liveness and readiness probes will not help as in this case the routing is suspended temporarily after being alive for some time. And pod should not be killed as it is still serving live user sessions.

I would love to hear about how you have dealt with this scenario in your case.

Comment: What do you mean? If the pod should be killed, you should probably terminated the stream as well?

Comment: @jonas that was a typo. I meant "pod should not be killed".

Comment: you can temporarily suspend traffic at node level

Comment: These pods are receiving data from a remote gRPC service (outside the cluster) and publishing to a queue within the cluster. From which another service reads and sends data to the client's WebSockets.

Comment: @TusharMahajan But then their would be other pods running on the same node that are completely healthy and ready. BTW, how could I temporarily ask my service to stop routing to a node? Can you give a few pointers ?

Comment: you can follow this, for stopping traffic to go to a node temporarily https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245667/force-moving-a-pod-from-one-worker-node-to-another/59250453#59250453

Comment: if you simply want to keep the pods alive and don't serve the traffic then how about de-registering the pod from the service, i.e. you have to redeploy the service component temporarily

Comment: Could you provide more details, environment information, versions, configuration manifests?